# Databricks result cache

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Does Databricks have the concept of a results cache? When I run a SQL query, does it cache the resultset somewhere for sub-second access or do we only have the Delta lake cache? I could not find anything in the documentation and at this stage am assuming it does not exist as a feature. Can someone clarify?

Comment: As far as I am aware, this is not possible, the documentation does touch of clearing the cache to improve performance, but nothing to do with this specific question. I hope this clarifies the future answer a tad more.

Comment: There is a concept called delta cache in databricks platform. you might want to check, which is different from spark cache. The Delta cache contains local copies of remote data. It can improve the performance of a wide range of queries, but cannot be used to store results of arbitrary subqueries.  See https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/delta-cache.html.

Comment: delta cache is very different to a result cache. With delta cache the data is cached on local nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Cache the data accessed by the specified simple **SELECT query** in the **Delta cache**. You can choose a subset of columns to be cached by providing a list of column names and choose a subset of rows by providing a predicate. This enables subsequent queries to avoid scanning the original files as much as possible. This construct is applicable only to Parquet tables. Views are also supported, but the expanded queries are restricted to the simple queries.

**Examples:**

```
CACHE SELECT * FROM boxes
CACHE SELECT width, length FROM boxes WHERE height=3
```

**Reference:** See [Delta and Apache Spark caching comparison](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/delta-cache.html#delta-and-rdd-cache-comparison) for the differences between the RDD cache and the Databricks IO cache.

The Delta cache accelerates data reads by creating copies of remote files in nodes’ local storage using a fast intermediate data format. The data is cached automatically whenever a file has to be fetched from a remote location. Successive reads of the same data are then performed locally, which results in significantly improved reading speed.

There are two types of caching available in Databricks:

- Delta caching
- Apache Spark caching

You can use Delta caching and Spark caching at the same time. This section outlines the key differences between them so that you can choose the best tool for your workflow.

**Type of stored data:** The Delta cache contains local copies of remote data. It can improve the performance of a wide range of queries, but cannot be used to store results of arbitrary subqueries. The Spark cache can store the result of any subquery data and data stored in formats other than Parquet (such as CSV, JSON, and ORC).

**Performance:** The data stored in the Delta cache can be read and operated on faster than the data in the Spark cache. This is because the Delta cache uses efficient decompression algorithms and outputs data in the optimal format for further processing using whole-stage code generation.

**Automatic vs manual control:** When the Delta cache is enabled, data that has to be fetched from a remote source is automatically added to the cache. This process is fully transparent and does not require any action. However, to preload data into the cache beforehand, you can use the CACHE command (see Cache a subset of the data). When you use the Spark cache, you must manually specify the tables and queries to cache.

**Disk vs memory-based:** The Delta cache is stored entirely on the local disk, so that memory is not taken away from other operations within Spark. Due to the high read speeds of modern SSDs, the Delta cache can be fully disk-resident without a negative impact on its performance. In contrast, the Spark cache uses memory.

Hope this helps.